# Hive can't use spark as default engine

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

When I use `hive> set hive.execution.engine=spark;`, hive can use spark as default engine. However when I write it in `hive-site.xml`. It can't work.

My hive-site.xml likes this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?><!--
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
   this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
   The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
   the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
-->
<configuration>
  <!-- WARNING!!! This file is auto generated for documentation purposes ONLY! -->
  <!-- WARNING!!! Any changes you make to this file will be ignored by Hive.   -->
  <!-- WARNING!!! You must make your changes in hive-site.xml instead.         -->
  <!-- Hive Execution Parameters -->
  <property>
    <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
    <value>spark</value>
    <description>Use spark as default engine. </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
    <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>root</value>
    <description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>vincent</value>
    <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: When the hive service starts, do you see it referencing the hive-site.xml in the Java command?  Maybe it's not reading the config file and going with internal defaults?

Comment: Yes,that's the problem is. And now I had fixed it. Thanks!